# how to calculate the minimal polynomial of this operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, minimal-polynomials

Let $V$ be the space of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ (with degree $\leq n$).

Let $T\colon V\to V$ be an operator on $V$ such that $T(P(x))=P(x+1)+P(x-1)$.

How can I calculate the characteristic and the minimal polynomial of $T$? I don't know how to turn this into a matrix.

Comment: Using the standard basis, the entries of the matrix are binomials:$$(x+1)^k + (x-1)^k = \sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom k\ell x^\ell + \sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom k\ell (-1)^{k-\ell}x^\ell = \sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom k\ell (1+(-1)^{k-\ell})x^\ell.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show for $k\ge 1$ by induction that

1. $(T-2)^k\{x^0,x^1,\ldots,x^{2k-1}\}=0$ and
2. $(T-2)^kx^{2k} = (2k)!$,

where $T-2$ is just a short form of $T-2I$. From this it easily follows that the smallest integer $m$ satisfying $(T-2)^m=0$ is $m = \lceil\frac{n+1}2\rceil$. Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $T$ is given by $\chi(x) = (x-2)^m$.

**Proof of 1.** The claim clearly holds for $k=1$. Assume it holds for $k\ge 1$. Then $(T-2)^{k+1}\{x^0,\ldots,x^{2k-1}\}=0$. Now,
\begin{align*}
(T-2)^{k+1}x^{2k}
&= (T-2)^k(T-2)x^{2k} = (T-2)^k\big[(x+1)^{2k} + (x-1)^{2k} - 2x^{2k}\big]\\
&= (T-2)^k\left[\sum_{\ell=0}^{2k}\binom{2k}\ell x^\ell + \sum_{\ell=0}^{2k}\binom{2k}\ell (-1)^{\ell}x^\ell - 2x^{2k}\right]\\
&= (T-2)^k\left[x^{2k} + x^{2k} - 2x^{2k}\right] = 0
\end{align*}
because $(T-2)^k$ annihilates each summand for $\ell=0,\ldots,2k-1$. Also,
\begin{align*}
(T-2)^{k+1}x^{2k+1}
&= (T-2)^k\big[(x+1)^{2k+1}+(x-1)^{2k+1}-2x^{2k+1}\big]\\
&= (T-2)^k\left[\sum_{\ell=0}^{2k+1}\binom{2k+1}\ell x^\ell + \sum_{\ell=0}^{2k+1}\binom{2k+1}\ell (-1)^{\ell-1}x^\ell - 2x^{2k+1}\right].
\end{align*}
For $\ell=0,\ldots,2k-1$ every summand in the two sums gets annihilated by $(T-2)^k$. Hence, we are left with $\ell = 2k$ and $\ell = 2k+1$. For $\ell = 2k$ the two summands annihilate each other and for $\ell = 2k+1$ the two summands equal $x^{2k+1}$ which then gets annihilated by $-2x^{2k+1}$. This proves 1.

**Proof of 2.** The proof is similar. For $k=1$ (actually also for $k=0$) the claim is evident. So, assume that 2. holds for some $k$. Then
\begin{align*}
(T-2)^{k+1}x^{2k+2}
&= (T-2)^k\big[(x+1)^{2k+2} + (x-1)^{2k+2} - 2x^{2k+2}\big]\\
&= (T-2)^k\left[\sum_{\ell=0}^{2k+2}\binom{2k+2}\ell x^\ell + \sum_{\ell=0}^{2k+2}\binom{2k+2}\ell (-1)^{\ell-2}x^\ell - 2x^{2k+2}\right].
\end{align*}
By 1., $(T-2)^k$ annihilates each summand for $\ell=0,\ldots,2k-1$. Furthermore, for $\ell=2k+2$ the summands are equal and are annihilated by $-2x^{2k+2}$. For $\ell = 2k+1$ the summands annihilate each other. So, we are left with $\ell = 2k$ and obtain
$$
(T-2)^{k+1}x^{2k+2} = 2\binom{2k+2}{2k}(T-2)^kx^{2k} = (2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)! = (2(k+1))!.
$$

Comment: +1.................................

Comment: @Aqua Thank you! I'll also upvote yours, now.

Answer (score 1):

If $n=3$ then basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ maps to $\{2,2x,2x^2+2,2x^3+6x\}$. So we can represent $T$ with matrix $$T=\begin{bmatrix}{2,0,2,0\\ 0,2,0,6\\0,0,2,0\\0,0,0,2}\end{bmatrix}$$
Can you finish now?

Comment: Yeah for sure, it is 6 at the 2,4 entry but I got the idea. The comment of @amsmath was very helpful too, thank you.

Comment: I don't get how this observation can be extrapolated to general $n$. Can someone elaborate, pls?

Comment: It was just an idea to get a feeling what is going on. @amsmath